# shall I use a global variable in multithreading if I just read it rather than writing?

Tags: multithreading, qt, c++11

I want to use 3 threads in my qt project,while using a global pointer array variable,3 threads will not change  it`s value

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that the contents of the global variable will never change during the time it is accessible to multiple threads, then it is safe for the threads to read that global variable without doing any synchronization.